# How to check, whether a Date is nil or not?

Tags: swift

I have a `class` name Person having below setter and getter.

```
private var _signedDate:Date? = nil
var signedDate:Date {
    get {
        return _signedDate!
    }
    set (newDate) {
        _signedDate = newDate
    }
}
```

As I have a variable 'signedDate` – I want to make a check function to let a person knows if he has signed or not. So for that, I am thinking to write a function like this:

```
func hasSigned() -> Bool {
    if signedDate {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Now the compiler giving me the following error:

> 'Date' is not convertible to 'Bool'.

In Obj-C, we could simply check for `nil` of a particular variable. But with the case of Swift, this has been changed.

**What should I do?**

With a case of `String`, there's a method: `isEmpty()`. But no such methods available for `Date`.

Comment: Note that `isEmpty()` does **NOT** check if the string is nil.  It checks if the string has no characters (i.e. `""`), which isn't the same thing.  Date has no equivalent to an empty string, so it doesn't have a similar method.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery, this is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you cannot forcibly unwrap `_signedDate` always when accessing `signedDate` since it will throw a run time error if `_signedDate` is nil.

Either have a default value for `signedDate` when `_signedDate` is nil, or expose `signedDate` to be also of type `Date?`.

One can check if a date is nil by using:

```
func hasSigned() -> Bool {
    if _signedDate == nil {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

To provide a default date (if it makes sense):

```
private var _signedDate:Date? = nil
var signedDate:Date {
    get {
        return _signedDate ?? Date() // or some valid date
    }
    set (newDate) {
        _signedDate = newDate
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of passing default value with the case of `nil`. However, writing this line, `if signedDate == nil` will give this warning. `Comparing the non-optional value of type 'Date' to nil always returns false`. Why have you suggested using `if _signedDate == nil`?

Comment: Because `_signedDate` is the optional type. You can only check nil against an optional type.

Comment: Thanks, one last question, what will be the `hasSigned()` function, if `private var _signedDate:Date = Date()`?

Comment: In that case, `_signedDate` is not nullable. It does not have an optional type. It doesn't make sense to have a `hasSigned()` function since its body will be `return true`.

Comment: Yes, understandable. Appreciated. However, at some point in code, what if I will have to do some UI changes based on `if person.hasSigned(){...}` ?

Comment: This is a bit tangential to the question at hand - since you are trying to combine the value of a date variable with the semantics of a logical action, i.e. whether the user has signed or not, I would suggest you to check Swift enums. You could have an enum
`enum SignedState` with cases `notSigned` and `signed(date: Date)`.

Answer (score 5):

Just type:

```
return _signedDate != nil
```

Comment: This is giving the following warning: `Comparing non-optional value of type 'Date' to nil always returns true`

Comment: @Hemang yes sorry, `_signedDate` var must be checked not `signedDate`

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the instance of `Date` to `nil` , thats it ! :)

```
if _signedDate == nil
{
     print("Found Nil")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **do not** use private backing variables in Swift.

Just declare the variable this way, even assigning `nil` is not needed.

```
var signedDate : Date?
```

Second of all, usually you check for `nil` at the moment you need the unwrapped value. If the check passes the if condition `date` is unwrapped (non-`nil`). Please read the paragraph *Optional Binding* in [Swift Language Guide - The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309)

```
if let date = signedDate {
  print(date)
} else {
  // signedDate is nil
}
```

or with `guard` to exit a function / method

```
guard let date = signedDate else { return }
print(date)
```

---

However if you want a function which returns a `Bool` write

```
func hasSigned() -> Bool {
    return signedDate != nil
}
```

or as a computed variable

```
var hasSigned : Bool { 
   return signedDate != nil  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vadian, for given your time to help me understand the concept a bit deeper.